# Is it possible to remove each Tox virtualenv once its env processing is done

Tags: python, tox

Is it possible to remove each Tox virtualenv once its env processing  is done?
I know, this is a weird usage, but I have a Tox configuration with hundreds of environment.

I want to run them one by one, but is it possible to remove each virtualenv once its processing is done?

Comment: `rm .tox/{envname}` might just work if you place it at the end of your `commands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with configuration. You need to remove the environment from the commands of the environment; the path is [{envdir}](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections). And you have to whitelist the program that removes directories. Something like this:

```
[testenv]
commands =
    {envpython} --version
    {envpython} -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
    rm -rf {envdir}
whitelist_externals =
    rm
```

Comment: It works! I used `/bin/rm` instead of `rm` in *whitelist_externals*. And used `commands_post` for `/bin/rm -rf {envdir}`.